# How to give viewers custom CSS option

Tags: css, iframe

I am looking for a solution to a kind of odd problem. I am creating a website whose intended purpose is to be embedded in to other peoples websites using an iframe. I want the people who embedd the iframe to be able to customize the CSS of my website. I do not want the viewer of the iframe to be able to customize the CSS but the embedder. I am not sure how I would go about doing that. Any suggestions?

Comment: We do this already for our product which adds a toolbar to the sites of hotels and makes it possible for their customers to make/cancel reservations, etc. We have a pre-defined set of CSS rules which are allowed to be customized which the hotel owners can edit in their profile.

Comment: you can pass some properties through the iframe url. Ex: example.com/?color=blue&size=2&..., you can retrieve those values in the iframe and customize the css

Comment: Depends on how much free space you want to give the client, can he change everything or just specified parameters? Is PHP an option?

Comment: I was thinking about something along the lines of the client being able to set {cssSrc = '/iframe.css'} in the iframe html. I don't think the iframe url would be really efficient. I expect them to have complete control. How would you go about doing it with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I would handle this is to have the user be able to provide a get parameter to select the css file form a server, e.g.

```
http://www.YourSite.com/page/?css-file=http://www.site.com/path/to/file.css
```

And based on the get parameter your server(or the client) would (using Django, php, or possibly in the client using javascript) load the provided css file.

Comment: This only solves the problem if I have predefined CSS files, Have the client Host a CSS file on a sharing site, or only want them to customize a few aspects of the site like background.

Comment: My bad I thought you meant you provided preset styles. Very similar concept, just have them provide the css file to load. Answer edited